# Generating a synthetic training set of sparse vectors

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I want to generate a dataset of length N sparse vectors in python. I am using scipy.sparse.rand to generate a matrix as follows -

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps
x_train_unnorm = sps.random(N, m, density=d, format='coo', dtype=None, random_state=None).toarray()
```

m here being the number of training samples and d the percentage of non-zero elements. Now the problem is that this command generates a sparse matrix with the overall percentage of non-zero elements d. I want to ensure that each column has no more than d percent non-zero elements. Is there a way to achieve it wthout using a loop?

Comment: Sparse nonzero locations and/or sparse values?  Sparse or is dense ok?  A loop approach is `sparse.vstack([sps.random(1,m,...) for _ in range(N)])`.  That will generate 1 row matrices and join their `coo` attributes to make a `(N,m)`.